# Python Rearrange order of a list according to element contents

Tags: python, list

I have a list of filenames, presently ordered by their 'file category', eg:

```
list = ['categorya.1.file','categorya.2.file','categoryb.1.file','categoryc.1.file']
```

The number of possible categories are arbitrary. The number of files in a given category are arbitrary.

I wish to rearrange the list so it reads one of each category at a time. So the above list would be rearranged to:

```
newlist = ['categorya.1.file', 'categoryb.1.file', 'categoryc.1.file', 'categorya.1.file']
```

The length of these lists could be massive, so I would assume efficiency is key. What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: The _best_ way depends on what exactly you're doing, where this list is coming from, and what the real data looks like.

Comment: I've removed the context for simplicity. But what I have is a list of filenames that I want to read in in a particular order. To achieve this I want to reorder the list in the way described in the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following looks worse than it should it simply uses `groupby` to break up the list into lists by their category and then combines those lists into a single list using `roundrobin`.

Using itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby, islice, cycle

# The following is from the itertools recipes 
# but it has had its splot removed for simplicity
def roundrobin(iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))

test_list = ['categorya.1.file','categorya.2.file','categoryb.1.file','categoryc.1.file']
new_list = list(roundrobin(list(list(l) for (c, l) in groupby(test_list, lambda v: v.split('.')[0]))))
print new_list
```

Prints:

```
['categorya.1.file', 'categoryb.1.file', 'categoryc.1.file', 'categorya.2.file']
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to sort by the digits casting to int, using the last letter to break ties:

```
lst = ['categoryc.2.file','categorya.1.file','categorya.2.file',
       'categoryb.2.file','categoryb.1.file','categoryc.1.file']

def key(x):
    spl = x.split(".",2)
    return int(spl[1]),spl[0][-1]
lst.sort(key=key)
```

Output:

```
['categorya.1.file', 'categoryb.1.file', 'categoryc.1.file',
'categorya.2.file', 'categoryb.2.file', 'categoryc.2.file']
```

If you don't care about the order once the categories are grouped then just use the `int`:

```
lst = ['categoryc.2.file','categorya.1.file','categorya.2.file',
       'categoryb.2.file','categoryb.1.file','categoryc.1.file']

lst.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(".",2)[1]))

print(lst)
['categorya.1.file', 'categoryb.1.file', 'categoryc.1.file', 
'categoryc.2.file', 'categorya.2.file', 'categoryb.2.file']
```

`.sort` is inplace so you don't need to create any other lists.